# SQL Server extended properties and management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, extended-properties

Hi
I have a sql server 2000 db and i added some extended properties to this db.
Then i installed sql server 2008 rc2 and management studio.
The problem when i want to open sql server 2008 db extended properties with management studio i just click right click on the db and it's there, but if i try this on a sql server 2000 db i can't find extended properties for it.

I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL 2000 you will probably have to use `SELECT * FROM ::fn_listextendedproperty(default, default, default, default, default, default, default)` to view the properties. I don't believe there is any GUI visibility.